# Pontryagin Duality

Tags: duality-theorems, profinite-groups

A pro-p group is a profinite group in which every open normal subgroup has index equal to some power of p. Suppose G is pro-p Group. Then, Whether there is a natural bijection between $Hom_{cont}(G, \Bbb Q_p/Z_p)$ and $Hom_{cont}(G, \Bbb Q/Z) $? (where $Q_p$ and $Z_p $ denotes the p-adic rationals and integers respectively.)

Comment: Just to clarify, by $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ you mean the $p$-adic rationals/integers?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk sure

Comment: sorry for the multiple edit (if someone saw them) originally I completely missed the point

Comment: "To be the same as set" is senseless. You should provide a natural map between these sets, and ask whether it is a bijection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $(\Bbb{Q/Z})[p^\infty]= \Bbb{Z[p^{-1}]/Z}\cong \Bbb{Q_p/Z_p}$
- That $G$ is a pro $p$-group (with the profinite topology) means $\forall g, \lim_{k \to \infty} [p^k] g = 0$,

  Whatever Hausdorff topology we put on $\Bbb{Q/Z}$,

  For a **continuous** homomorphism $f : G \to\Bbb{Q/Z}$ for all $g\in G$ we must have $\lim_{k \to \infty} [p^k] f(g) = 0$

  ( $\lim_{k \to \infty} [p^k] f(g)$ is in the discrete topology of the finite group generated by $f(g)$)

  which means $[p^r] f(g)=0$ and $f$ takes its values in $(\Bbb{Q/Z})[p^\infty]$.

Comment: $Q/Z$ is not discrete then why $[p^r] f(g)=0$?@reuns

Comment: the subgroup generated by $f(g)$ is discrete, equivalently if $f(g)$ is not of order $p^r$ then $[p^k]f(g)$ is periodic as $k \to \infty$. I should probably say "whatever Hausdorff topology we put on $\Bbb{Q/Z}$"